# Boundary condition of a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations, partial-functions

I am currently working on this paper "https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.02523" about travel time options and I am stuck at Theorem 14 page 20. The proof is similar to Theorem 7.5.1, "Stochastic Calculus for finance II, continuous time model" from Shreve. Just a different underlying process.
I do not understand the last boundary condition.
Here the underlying process is given by
\begin{align*}
 dX_t=(-a_1X_t+\gamma_t)dt+dW_t\\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    Y_t=\int_{0}^{t}X_udu\
\end{align*}
The boundary condtion is given by
\begin{align*}
 v(t,0,y)=e^{-r(T-t)}\max(\frac{y}{T}-K,0).
\end{align*}
Derivation from **Shreve** ($dX_t=rX_tdt+X_tdW_t$):

> If $X_t=0$ and $Y_t=y$ for some variable $t$, then $X_u=0, \ \forall u \in[t,T]$ and so $Y_u$ is constant on $[t,T]$ and therefore $Y_T=y$ and the value of the Asian call option at time t is $e^{-r(T-t)}\max(\frac{y}{T}-K,0)$.

I understand his derivation (see https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/78206/pricing-pde-of-asian-option-by-shreve)
**Problem**:
The author of my paper gives no explanation to this boundary condition. But I don't think I can apply Shreve's explanation to my process, since it has no $X_t$ before the $dW_t$ term and can therefore take non-zero values again once it was zero?!

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The "boundary condition" $v(t,0,y)=e^{-r(T-t)}\max(\frac{y}{T}-K,0)$ is simply the payoff of the the option, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer:) Yes it is, but i think this implies, that if at time $t$ $X_t=0$ and $Y_t=y$ then $Y_t$ has to stay constant from $t$ to $T$, which on the other hand implies that $X_u=0, \forall u\in[t,T]$. In my opinion this is not the case of the process from the paper, in contrast to Shreve's process

Comment: This implication is on which page?

Comment: This follows the argumentation from Shreve (see question). This also makes sense to me, since at time $t$ we conclude the value $Y_T=y$, which is random if we do not assume that it is constant from $t$ to $T$.

Comment: The two processes are different. The process in Shreve is the log-normal process and when it touches $0$ at a $t$  then the entire process remains $0$ from then on. However, the process in the paper does not behave like that. And I don't know whether the authors wrote this implication you mentionned in this paper.

Comment: In the paper the authors just stated that "this boundary condition ist just the discounted payoff from $T$ to $t$". I understand that this is the payoff, but i do not unterstand why we can conclude that $Y_T=y$

Comment: This boundary condition ist just the discounted *payoff* from $T$ to $t$. And the *price* (aka: *value* ) of the option is $e^{-r(T-t}\mathbb{E}^{Q}(\max(\frac{Y_T}{T}-K,0))$. I think the authors have never concluded that $Y_T = y = Y_0$ and the value of the option is $e^{-r(T-t}(\max(\frac{Y_0}{T}-K,0)$